# Ruby on Rails - how to pluck and update_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I currently am pulling some info out of

```
model_hash = Model.where(id: some_id, name: some_name).pluck(:name, :id).to_h
```

I'd like to update another attribute on every model that it sees. I know I can write:

```
Model.where(id: some_id, name: some_name).update_all(last_import_date: DateTime.now)
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way that I can combine the two statements

Comment: You could create a model method update_time, and use `.map(&:update_time)`, but there is probably a slicker way

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord `pluck` generates a SQL `SELECT` query while `update_all` generates a SQL `UPDATE` query. You can retrieve data during an `UPDATE` for certain SQL dialects, e.g. in PostgreSQL [you can use `RETURNING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-update.html) to specify which values you want returned from the updated rows. In your case, e.g.:

```
UPDATE models 
  SET last_import_date = '2017-04-04 20:49:07'
  WHERE name = 'Some Name'
  RETURNING id;
```

ActiveRecord doesn't support this, likely because its highly dialect-dependent, and ActiveRecord intends to abstract away from those differences.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any such thing is required. Your code is generally used. But if you really want to do this in one query you can try this.

```
model_hash = Map.where(id: some_id, name: some_name).map { |x| x.update_attributes(last_import_date: DateTime.now) ? [x.id, x.some_name] : ["value","nil"] }.to_h
```

Its a complex one though.
Hope this Helps...